# Are there any link shorteners that obtain IP Addresses?

Tags: ip-address

I have tried both bit.ly and goo.gl, but they both give the same info. Time clicked, referrers, and the country. However, I am wondering if there are any URL shorteners that obtain and show more info, such as IP Addresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can used bit.do. It is providing IP addresses of the clients accessing the link.